# C# JSON not parsing correctly using Newtownsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, deserialization

I have 2 classes, `LatLong` which holds 2 strings, `latitude and longitude`, and `LatLongs` which holds a `list<LatLong>`.

```
public class LatLongs
{
    public List<LatLong> latlongs { get; set; }
}

public class LatLong
{
    public string latitude { get; set; }
    public string longitude { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to use `Newtownsoft.Json` `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` function to convert my JSON string into a list of `LatLong`. Here is my JSON

```
[  
   {  
      "latitude":"-34.978113",
      "longitude":"138.516192"
   },
   {  
      "latitude":"-34.978104",
      "longitude":"138.516648"
   },
   {  
      "latitude":"-34.978384",
      "longitude":"138.516660"
   },
   {  
      "latitude":"-34.978398",
      "longitude":"138.516225"
   }
]
```

This JSON is valid and has been checked [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

When I try to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` I am getting an exception

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'SafeAgSystems.Models.LatLongs' because the type requires a JSON
>   object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Here is the code I am using to attempt to convert the JSON into a list of `LatLong`

```
List<Locations> coords = await locationTable.Where(u => u.fk_company_id == viewModel.UserData.fk_company_id).ToListAsync();
List<LatLongs> latLongs = new List<LatLongs>();
for (int i = 0; i < coords.Count(); i++)
{
    LatLongs latlongs = new LatLongs();
    latlongs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LatLongs>(coords[i].geofence_coordinates);
    latLongs.Add(latlongs);

}
```

Another thing I have checked is that my `List<Locations> coords` is being populated, which is definitely is. I am completely stuck, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to deserialize to `LatLongs` which has one property named `latlongs` of type `List<LatLong>`. On the other hand, you're feeding it with a string that contains `List<LatLong>` (without `latlongs` property).

You need to change your code to

```
List<Locations> coords = await locationTable.Where(u => u.fk_company_id == 
viewModel.UserData.fk_company_id).ToListAsync();
List<LatLongs> latLongs = coords.Select(c => new LatLongs 
{ 
  latlongs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LatLong>>(c.geofence_coordinates) 
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan, you're a wizard!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not instantiating the list property. Try the code below

```
List<Locations> coords = await locationTable.Where(u => u.fk_company_id == viewModel.UserData.fk_company_id).ToListAsync();
List<LatLongs> latLongs = new List<LatLongs>();
for (int i = 0; i < coords.Count(); i++)
{
    LatLongs latlongs = new LatLongs();
    latlongs.latlongs = new List<LatLong>(); //Property instantiation
    latlongs.latlongs= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LatLongs>(coords[i].geofence_coordinates).ToList();
    latLongs.Add(latlongs);

}
```

You can also have constructor in the class to instantiate it.

Comment: Thanks Yousuf I'll give that a try and see how I go